# Can the Castle Windsor Factory implied by Type of T in Resolve<T>?

Tags: .net, castle-windsor, factory-pattern

I have the following castle windsor fluent config code ...

```
container
  .AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>()
  .Register(

  Component
    .For<IXxxCache>()
    .ImplementedBy<AppFabricXxxCache>()
    .Named("AppFabricXxxCache")
    .LifeStyle.FromContext(),

  Component
    .For<IXxxCache>()
    .ImplementedBy<DatabaseXxxCache>()
    .Named("DatabaseXxxCache")
    .LifeStyle.FromContext(),

  Component
    .For<IXxxCacheFactory>()
    .ImplementedBy<XxxCacheFactory>()
    .DependsOn(new {cacheName})
  );
```

The XxxCacheFactory is as follows ...

```
public class XxxCacheFactory : IXxxCacheFactory
{
    private readonly IWindsorContainer _container;
    private readonly string _cacheName;

    public XxxCacheFactory(IWindsorContainer container, string cacheName)
    {
        _container = container;
        _cacheName = cacheName;
    }

    public IXxxCache Create()
    {
        try
        {
            var cache = new DataCacheFactory().GetCache(_cacheName);
            return _container.Resolve<IXxxCache>("AppFabricXxxCache", new {cache});
        }
        catch (DataCacheException)
        {
            return _container.Resolve<IXxxCache>("DatabaseXxxCache");
        }
    }

    public void Release(IXxxCache component)
    {
        _container.Release(component);
    }
}
```

I can get this working with the following code ...

```
[Test]
public void database_xxx_cache_returned_when_cache_does_not_exist()
{
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CacheName"] = "this_cache_does_not_exist";
    var container = Castle.WindsorContainerBootStrap.BootStrapContainerAndRunInstallers<SingletonLifestyleManager>();
    var factory = container.Resolve<IXxxCacheFactory>();
    var cache = factory.Create();
}
```

Ideally I'd like to cut out the factory creation part and just have the container get the the correct implementation using the factory class I have, like so ...

```
[Test]
public void database_xxx_cache_returned_when_cache_does_not_exist()
{
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CacheName"] = "this_cache_does_not_exist";
    var container = Castle.WindsorContainerBootStrap.BootStrapContainerAndRunInstallers<SingletonLifestyleManager>();
    var cache = container.Resolve<IXxxCache>();
}
```

Is this possible? If so, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my colleagues pointed me at the factory method support of Windsor

Just adding this to my installer has got it working ...

```
container
    .Register(
        Component
            .For<DataCacheFactory>()
            .ImplementedBy<DataCacheFactory>()
            .LifeStyle.Singleton
        ,
        Component
            .For<IXxxCacheFactory>()
            .ImplementedBy<XxxCacheFactory>()
            .DependsOn(new {cacheName})
            .LifeStyle.Transient
        ,
        Component
            .For<IXxxCache>()
            .UsingFactoryMethod(kernel => kernel.Resolve<IXxxCacheFactory>().Create())
        ,
        Component
            .For<IXxxCache>()
            .ImplementedBy<AppFabricXxxCache>()
            .Named("AppFabricXxxCache")
            .LifeStyle.FromContext()
        ,
        Component
            .For<IXxxCache>()
            .ImplementedBy<DatabaseXxxCache>()
            .Named("DatabaseXxxCache")
            .LifeStyle.FromContext()
     );
```

I've also used the container to create the DataCacheFactory as that is apparently an expensive operation. So the usage is now ...

```
[Test]
public void database_xxx_cache_returned_when_cache_does_not_exist()
{
    // ARRANGE
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CacheName"] = "this_cache_does_not_exist";
    var container = Castle.WindsorContainerBootStrap.BootStrapContainerAndRunInstallers<SingletonLifestyleManager>();

    // ACT
    var cache = container.Resolve<IXxxCache>();

    // ASSERT
    Assert.That(cache, Is.InstanceOf<DatabaseXxxCache>());

    // TIDYUP
    container.Dispose();
}
```